# When I package use_frameworks, the package gets bigger. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

- cocoapods Version: 1.8.4
- iOS Version: 13.1
- Xcode Version: 11.3.1
- swift Version: 5.0.1

The packages get larger when I use **use_frameworks** packages, and when I look at the contents of the packages I find that there are more packages corresponding to **xx.frameworks.dsyms** in the **dSYMs** folder

- q1: what happened here?
- q2: should I use **use_frameworks** without considering blending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `use_frameworks` causes your pods to be built into dynamic frameworks, which take more space than static linking.

However, if you update CocoaPods to 1.9.0 you can enjoy both worlds by writing:

```rb
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

See the details in [CocoaPods blog](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.9.0-beta/).